# Java, is there a performance advantage to using members?

Tags: java

Is there a performance advantage to using member variables in the below case? It seems like there is, but I'm not sure what it would be. Something to do with the member being allocated a memory location when it's value is first assigned, so when it is reassigned it doesn't need a new one? Or something about Garbage Collection performance?

Regardless, with the two snippets below, is one more performant? (`aMethod` gets called frequently)

```
class a {
  Object x;

  void aMethod () {
     x = //...
   }
}

class a {

  void aMethod () {
     Object x = //...
  }
}
```

Comment: Memory allocation happens when you do `new MyObject()`. It does not happen when you assign an object to a variable or field.

Comment: The performance is completely irrelevant--choose based on what accurately models your data. If `x` isn't actually some property of `a`, then don't make it a member. In particular, the second version is thread-safe and the first isn't.